# Gmail REST API, create draft with default "Send mail as" address

Tags: api, gmail

The following python statement creates a draft email for one of our users:

```
draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId='me', body=message).execute()
```

It does not, however, set the `from` field to the default "Send mail as" address, as previously specified by the user in a browser (Gmail > Settings > Accounts).

(After the draft email is generated programmatically as shown above, the user can manually adjust the "from" field, to select the default from the drop down list of available send addresses.)

Is there a way to programmatically generate a draft email such that the `from` field is the "Send mail as" default? In other words, is there a way to programmatically generate such that the `from` field is the same as if the draft email were manually generated in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was programmatically setting the email from field: message['from'] = "smith23@gmail.com", where "smith23@gmail.com" is present in the drop down list of available send addresses.  This was overriding the default "Send mail as" address, as previously specified by the user in a browser (Gmail > Settings > Accounts).

The solution was to not set message['from'].